# Release variables defined inside a block

Tags: objective-c, ios5, objective-c-blocks

Looking at this code (ARC turned on):

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

dispatch_queue_t fetchDataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Fetch Data Queue", nil);
dispatch_async(fetchDataQueue, ^{
    NSArray *temp = [Product retrieveProductsByName:searchString];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _products = [temp copy];
        [controller.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    });
});
dispatch_release(fetchDataQueue);
return NO;
}
```

Is it really safe? Is my temp NSArray going to be automatically released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have ARC on that will be done automatic. And of course Mac OS X is a modern System and normally all your objects will be released if your app terminates.

Comment: More than just that, but because the `temp` array is alive in the scope of the block you're dispatching to the main queue, it will be retained *by* that block until it's finished, so this code is absolutely safe.